# Setting row to minimum child height flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to produce a widget like this below to be contained inside of a listview. I have managed an effect like this rather simply based on the example given on the flutter website for YouTube. However, the part I'm struggling with is that I would like the image to resize vertically depending on how large the text is.

Currently this is created with a row. If possible I'd like to set the row height somehow but only dependent on the height of the text. As some elements will have more text and some will have less I would like to have the image fill the vertical space so the height is the same as the text height.

I basically want this - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html#material.ListTile.4
but where the image height on the left matches the text height on the right

Thanks in advance!

[image: intended outcome]

Comment: Wrap `Text` widget with expanded. If necessary wrap both with `Expadned` with property `flex`.

Comment: As Blansaka wrote, you may want to wrap `Text` widget with an `expanded` widget to achieve that, here is some example: [Flutter Expanded widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) they put some expanded inside a Row to achieve similar effect.

Comment: This is not possible by current widgets as you to decide one widget height based on the other.